# Hacer un insert multiple dentro de una transaccion MySql c#

Tags: c#, mysql

debo crear un registro en una tabla "pedidos" y luego con el "id_pedido" ir agregando los productos de ese pedido en la tabla "pedidos_pos" para esto cree la siguiente transacción:

```
MySqlTransaction tr = null;
        try
        {
            //inserto el registro del pedido en la tabla pedidos

            // Abro la conexion
            SqlCon.Open();
            // Inicializo la transaccion
            tr = SqlCon.BeginTransaction();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

            string consulta = "INSERT INTO pedidos (id_fabrica, año, fecha, id_cliente, id_vendedor, ruta, importe_total, impuestos, observacion, transporte, fecha_entrega, hora_entrega, domicilio_transporte) " +
                "SELECT fabrica.ID_FABRICA, ?año, @fecha, cliente.ID_CLIENTE, vendedor.ID_VENDEDOR, @ruta, @importe_total, @impuestos, @observacion, @transporte, @fecha_entrega, @hora_entrega, concat(cliente.CALLE, ' ', cliente.ALTURA, ' ', cliente.CIUDAD, ' ', cliente.REGION) AS DOMICILIO_TRANSPORTE " +
                "FROM fabrica, vendedor, cliente " +
                "WHERE fabrica.NOMBRE = @cbFabrica and vendedor.NOMBRE = @cbVendedor and cliente.nombre = @txtCliente ; " +
                "select last_insert_id();";

            cmd = new MySqlCommand(consulta, SqlCon, tr);                
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?año", DateTime.Today.Year);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss"));                
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ruta", txtRuta.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@importe_total", importe_total);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@impuestos", impuestos);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@observacion", txtObservaciones.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transporte", txtTransporte.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha_entrega", dtpFecha.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hora_entrega", mtxtHora.Text);                
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cbFabrica", cbFabrica.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cbVendedor", cbVendedor.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtCliente", txtCliente.Text);


            id_pedido = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

            //creacion de los insert de la tabla pedidos_pos

            foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (fila.Cells["cantidad"].Value != null)
                {

                     consulta = "INSERT INTO pedidos_pos (id_fabrica, id_pedido, año, importe, id_producto, cantidad, precio_unitario)" +
                       " VALUES ( @id_fabrica, @id_pedido, @año, @importe, @id_producto, @cantidad, @precio_unitario ); ";
                    cmd = new MySqlCommand(consulta, SqlCon);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_fabrica", fila.Cells["id_fabrica"].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_pedido", id_pedido);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@año", DateTime.Today.Year);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@importe", fila.Cells["importe"].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_producto", fila.Cells["id_producto"].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cantidad", fila.Cells["cantidad"].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@precio_unitario", fila.Cells["precio_unitario"].Value);


                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
            }

            tr.Commit();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            tr.Rollback();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            SqlCon.Close();
        }
```

Este código me funciona, pero no se si están bien implementados los dos insert en la transacción.
Por otro lado el segundo insert, es decir el de la tabla pedidos_pos esta dentro de un loop, no se si eso podría traer problemas de performance, por lo que me gustaría hacer algo como crear un insert múltiple con la forma:

```
INSERT INTO pedido_pos (columna1, columna2, etc) VALUES(valor1,valor2,etc)(valor1,valor2,etc);
```

dentro del loop para luego ejecutarlo por fuera del loop, para no hacer un insert por cada vuelta, solo que no se me ocurre como llevarlo a cabo, o si es util, alguna idea?

Comment: Tu implemantación es correcta. En este escenario, no hay ningún problema con ejecutar un ``insert``en un loop.